# How to guarantee that no matter activity is stopped or killed by system that volley request always can be canceled?

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley recommend that we can cancel request in **onStop** method of activity, but **onStop** may never be called, the official doc says:

> Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's process running after its onPause() method is called.

So the problem is when the **onStop** method isn't be called, how to guarantee the related request can be canceled.

The only solution I can found:
cancel the requests both in **onSaveInstance** and **onStop** method of activity .Because when activity is killed by system  **onSaveInstance** is guaranteed to be called.
But I doubt whether it's appropriate.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote: you have a lot of questions without an official answer. You need to set one in order for other readers to know if those answers worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

use volley call in fragment with setRetaininstance(true);

```
public class FragmentConnect extends Fragment {


    boolean attatched=false;

    public FragmentConnect() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        attatched=false;
     }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        attatched=true;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

        attatched=true;
        setRetainInstance(true);



        if(savedInstanceState!=null){



        }else{
            //call while creating fragment
            callToServer();
        }








        return rootView;

    }

    private void callToServer() {
        if(attatched){

            //call_volley here
         }
    }
```